# Copying one HTML table to another page

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

Currently I am working on a small dashboard used for my job, however, I am stuck with one part of it. The main idea (will skip the specific of the dashboard) is the following:

I have a big table of data on one page - regular HTML table, 9 columns, but a huge amount of rows - the number varies. I have to copy that table and insert it into another page and then pass that table as some sort of array to make some calculations with it. Is that possible? Do you any thoughts on how to do this? Is there some sort of text area that would accept the HTML table as it is to pass it to PHP then? Any solutions would be acceptable.

Comment: Be aware that POST have a limitation and it's not a good practice do what you want. Why you can generate the table in the final page?

Comment: It's not really clear to me the specifics of what you're describing.  You tagged the question with PHP, but how is PHP involved here?  You say it's a "regular HTML table", so it this just static text in an HTML file?  And you want to copy it to a second file?  Can't you just copy it from one to the other and save the file?  Or you're trying to automate this so the second file is just a dynamic view of the first one?  What is your actual source of data?  Why not have a back-end database and each page just displays that data?

Comment: Because I don't have access to the server of the page where I will take the data from. As the info that I am getting is the table only, think of it as of the third-party data source

Comment: @David, don't have access to the database of the first page. All I have is the HTMl table, I have to make the following things happen:
1. User (my colleagues) will copy the HTML table with data
2. They will copy that data to another page - the dashboard I am currently working on
3. Dashboard will make calculations based on the data pasted inside

Comment: @a.sedihs: Then it sounds like what you're doing is "screen scraping".  Look up things like CURL and an HTML DOM Parser to make HTTP requests in code, read the HTML returned by those requests, and parse data from that HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have access to the server to add javascript to the page it's not possible to do what you want in the way that you are asking.

One way forward is to build a php script to load the page using CURL and then you can process the page however you wish.

you might want to look at [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://PHP%20Simple%20HTML%20DOM%20Parser) this php tool allows you load in an external php file and process it, looking for certain html tags and extract the data.

Comment: Or more generally, Google for "screen scraping", and choose the tool that's most convenient for you.  There are many, many options - including cUrl.